# How to filter data for dropdown options based on previous selected?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I will try to explain shortly. I have this:

[image]

I am using AntDesign library with React, and these are not regular inputs, but Autocomplete dropdowns, when i focus on one of them it gives me a list of options to choose. So first i have to choose first dropdown value and after that i will get options in next one to choose, then i choose second and after that i get options for third and so on. So it is something like a chain, you must select all previous dropdowns to be able to get options and select current.

[image]

This is what i get from backend.
[image]

The normal thing would be that i get values for first dropdown and after i select value i call endpoint again which will return options for second one and so on. But no, i get all possible combination of values in one array, and now i have to filter that one big array each time i select value in one of the dropdowns, to get values for next one, so for the SCOPE for instance, i have to filter array depending on 3 selected previous values and so on for the others.
Last two fields are not important for this problem.

So, i need help how to filter these values in the easiest way. And to use Form.Item and Autocomplete from AntDesign.

Comment: Did you search for cascade dropdowns like this: https://ant.design/components/cascader/

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Could you be more specific about your requirement and the structure of your data? Is it that the list is flat, and each selected value reduces results, or is it that values are nested, so when you select something, only values nested under that key remain available?